# Keyboard language configuration, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I would like to change keyboard language, I need to have German one. 
Here is what I did:
1. I opened Language Support and I installed both Deutsch and German language.
2. Then I opend Text Entry window and I wanted to add new language as a input source, so I tap "+" and there was nothing. I use Polish keyboard but it is also not listed down in "input sources to use".

Could you tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: No obvious mistake. If not a long list of options is shown when you click the "+" button in Text Entry ("select an input source to add"), your Ubuntu installation is probably not complete. As a first step, make sure that the `ubuntu-desktop` package is installed.

Comment: I decided to reinstall Ubuntu. This time I used english keyboard layout and everything is correct: "impuut sources to use" is not empty and also "select an input source to add" is full of languages, so I can add Polish and German. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

pehaps no one wrote the key mappings of your polish keyboard for german and deutsch use. Ubuntu used to have these problems, but latelly I've heard the keyboard support improved a lot.
try adding polish language. If it doesn't work just buy another keyboard or contribute to ubuntu with those mappings.